# Don't clear all notification when application open from notification

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

In my requirement I want to older notification. I will give you an example for more clearance.
i.g. Get

```
Notification 1
Notification 2
Notification 3
```

And I opened `Notification 3` and I don't want clear `Notification 1 and 2`.

Hope you are understand. Please help me

Comment: Launching your app by clicking on the notification shouldn't cause previous notifications to be removed from the notification screen unless your calling `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: removableIDs)` or `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()`

Comment: Yes that I know. But in my AppDelegate have not any code for remove notification.

Answer (score 0):

if you calls:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

this also clear all your notifications on locked device screen