# Is there a way of keeping notifications in the Notification Centre even after opened/interacted with

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, settings

I wanted to know if there was a way to keep messages in the Notification Centre in iOS 16. Even after the message has been responded to or the app has been opened.
I used to be able to do it on iOS 15 but on iOS 16 it seems to clear all messages after they have been interacted with. I recently moved over to a new iPhone and all the app settings have been copied across from the old phone.
In particular for apps like Slack and TikTok.

I’ve been through all the notification setting on my iPhone and I can’t seem to figure out why it works for some apps like Instagram, News and Twitter.

Comment: In my case, the first comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65968412/dont-clear-all-notification-when-application-open-from-notification) helped me with my problem.